# Mongodb - Setting the replication at the db or collection level

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I come across the following phase and I had fair idea of distributed systems like hdfs and elasticsearch etc ..

> A replica set in MongoDB is a group of mongod processes that maintain
> the same data set. Replica sets provide redundancy and high
> availability, and are the basis for all production deployments. This
> section introduces replication in MongoDB as well as the components
> and architecture of replica sets. The section also provides tutorials
> for common tasks related to replica sets.

In all those distributed systems like hdfs , elasticsearch - we can set the replication factor at the file level or index level. It seems it is not possible to do with mongo db, the only way to do the replication with mongodb is at the *instance / process* level - which means the machines in the replicaset group will have similar data no matter what.

Isnt it possible to create the replication at the *db* level ?

Comment: Your understanding of the replication as mentioned in the documentation is correct.  Only, the _sharding_  is at collection level (this applies for sharded clusters)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MongoDB replica set, each document is stored on each node (hence the replication factor is the number of nodes, and it is not configurable).

The benefit of this design is each node can answer any query from its locally stored data, without needing to retrieve data from other nodes.

Comment: which also means that all nodes will always have almost _same_ storage as they will all contain the same amount of data. And each collection will have same replication factor equivalent number of replica sets